# Declaring function inside function in C

Tags: c, function, function-pointers, function-declaration

I found this question on an online exam. This is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int demo();
    demo();
    (*demo)();
    return 0;
}

int demo(){
    printf("Morning");
}
```

I saw the answer after the test. This is the answer:

```
MorningMorning
```

I read the explanation, but can't understand why this is the answer.
I mean, shouldn't the line `int demo();` cause any ***"problem"***?

Any explanation is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre It's not a duplicate of that question. Declaring a function inside a function is very different from defining a function inside a function.

Comment: ok, reopened. The answers below don't answer about the `(*demo)();` bit.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre can you please explain that part (you can post a separate answer).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a problem because that `int demo();` is not a function definition, it is just an external declaration, saying (declaring) that a function of such name exists.

In C you cannot define a nested function:

```
int main(void) {
    int demo() {} //Error: nested function!!!
}
```

But you can declare a function just fine. It is actually equivalent to:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int demo(); //function declaration, not definition

int main(void) {
    demo();
    (*demo)();
    return 0;
}

int demo(){
    printf("Morning");
}
```

except that in your code the external forward `demo()` declaration is only visible inside  `main`.

Comment: what's going to happen if I don't "declare" the function? I mean, I removed the line `int demo();` and it still works fine.

Comment: @DebanikDawn: Ah, that's because in C there is that infamous _automatic function declaration_, that in case you use a function without a previous declaration, the compiler will create one for you, taking whatever arguments you are passing and returning `int`... handy, maybe in the 1970s, but very dangerous. Turn on your compiler warnings and you'll see the danger (and keep them on!).

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can declare a function inside another function. This is allowed. The only thing is it is visible only inside the function in which it is declared.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers didn't explain the

```
(*demo)();
```

part. Here's a partial explanation:

`demo` (without parentheses) is the function *pointer*. So you can first dereference it to get a function *then* call it with parentheses (wrapping the dereferenced object into parentheses else it means that you want to dereference the *return value* of the function)

So it's strictly equivalent to

```
demo();
```

(the notation is useful when the function pointer is stored in a variable, here it's just more cryptic than necessary)

Comment: If `demo()` is same as `(*demo)()`, doesn't that imply `demo` and `*demo` is the exact same thing? How can that be?

Comment: P.S. I wrote a program in which I created a function `hello()` and then in the main function printed the values of `hello` and `*hello` and `&hello`. They are exactly the same, I don't get it.

Comment: ìt's just a question of notation. `hello` is the address of the routine. It's not like a normal variable. Getting the address of the address or dereferencing it has no effect.

Comment: Ah, okay. I understand now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`int main(void) { int demo(); /*...*/ }; int demo(){ /*...*/ }`
is equivalent to
`int main(void) { extern int demo(); /*...*/ }; int demo(){ /*...*/ }`
It declares the demo function with external linkage, inside the main function.
The `demo` identifier will be valid till the end of the scope, but `demo` will be a
normal, external function.

Unfortunately, you cannot do this for functions that are `static`, because 
the standard (http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#note30) makes things like
`int main(void) { static int demo(); } static int demo(){ /*...*/ }`
illegal.

As to why `(*demo)();` works and is in this context equivalent to `demo();` or `(&demo)();` or `(*&demo)();`:

After you declare demo with `int demo();`, `demo` is a function designator (which is not the same as a function pointer, not unlike an array designator is not the same as a pointer the the array's first element). Like arrays, though, function designators almost always decay to function pointers (see [6.3.2.1p4](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p4)) and this type of decay happens in function calls too. Essentially `demo();` decays `demo` to a pointer and then calls
the function pointer. Applying `*` to such a pointer yields again the function designator which again decays to a pointer to make the call.

Admittedly, all this stuff is very weird and esoteric and I can't even think of a situation where the distinction is useful. IMHO, it's probably best to stick to `demo();` or `(demo)()` (if you want to supress macro expansion) and never use `(*demo)()` (at least not on functions -- on function pointers it is at least somewhat informative) and especially not `(&demo)()` as it serves little purpose other than to confuse the reader.